# Java, random operator; call the same method into the method

Tags: java, random, callback

I am trying to learn Java. I have tried to solve a little problem. At this point I dont know what to try anymore. I want to generate 2 random numbers and 2 random operator (+/-). If the result of these is  between 0-20  print something, otherwise start over again until the result is in the range.
I am getting an error when I call the method: `randomQuestion();`
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExercicesMathQuizz {
Random random = new Random();
private int randomQuestion(){

    //generate 2 random numbers 
    int number = random.nextInt(15)+1;
    int number2 = random.nextInt(15)+1;
    //initiate result 
    int res = 0;
    //operator
    String operator =  randomOperator();

    //if operator is "+" do sum
    //otherwise do subtraction
    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        res = num1+num2;
        return res;
    }
    //if(operator.equals("-")) {
    else {
        res = num1-num2;
        return res;
    }

}

private void checkResult() {
     int res = randomQuestion();
     //if the result is between 0 and 20 (inclusive)
            if (res > 0 && res <= 20) {
                System.out.println(res + " is between 0-20"); 
            }
            else {
                //start over again with new numbers
                randomQuestion();
            }

    //generate a random operator
    private String randomOperator() {
    return random.nextBoolean() ? "+" : "-";

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the whole story, where's the code for randomOperator?

Comment: Could you please post the exception and code of  randomQuestion() ?

Comment: Please post the exception! Also post the randomOperator method

Comment: I just don't understand how did you manage to make a Static Variable inside a Method.

Comment: @NullPointer you mean the code of randomOperator()?

Comment: @Cristea better edit the question and provide it there. Not that we have to read it in this  format in comments :/ Also provide the error that you said you get in the question

Comment: private void checkResult() {
  int res = randomQuestion();
  //if the result is between 0 and 20 (inclusive)
    if (res > 0 && res <= 20) {
     System.out.println(res + " is between 0-20"); 
    }
    else {
     //start over again with new numbers
     randomQuestion();
    }

Comment: That is the code for the `checkResult()` method. Please post the code for `randomOperator()`

Comment: @GBlodgett and the exception too

Comment: @Joza100 Yeah that too

Comment: @Joza100 Yes, you are right. I mean was `randomOperator()` . Now I can't edit the comment . :/

Comment: I just ran your code and I got no exceptions. Can you please specify your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have the wrong variable names in some places. You initialize the two numbers as `number` and `number2` but later in the program you call `num1` and `num2` (I'm assuming these were meant to be the same variables.

2) You're missing a bracket after the `checkResult` method

3) You have all your methods as private. Depending on what you are trying to do, this might cause a problem.

4) You never call `checkResult()` from the `randomQuestion` method. And as it generates completely new results regardless of what you have in the `randomQuestion()` method, this is a problem. I would have the method accept an integer, check if it's valid and then return a Boolean variable. Then in `randomQuestion()` you can loop until the result is valid. Check the code below:

```
static Random random = new Random();
public void randomQuestion(){
    boolean valid = false;
    int res = 0;
    while(!valid) {
        //generate 2 random numbers 
        int number = random.nextInt(15)+1;
        int number2 = random.nextInt(15)+1;
        //initiate result 

        //operator
        String operator =  randomOperator();

        //if operator is "+" do sum
        //otherwise do subtraction
        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            res = number+number2;
            valid = checkResult(res);
        }
        //if(operator.equals("-")) {
        else {
            res = number-number2;
             valid = checkResult(res);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(res + " is between 1-20");
}

public boolean checkResult(int res) {
     //int res = randomQuestion();
     //if the result is between 0 and 20 (inclusive)
            if (res > 0 && res <= 20) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                //start over again with new numbers
                return false;
            }
    }
    //generate a random operator
    private String randomOperator() {
        return random.nextBoolean() ? "+" : "-";
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.randomQuestion();

  }
```

Comment: @Joza100 I don't think so she knows it and using any editor.

Comment: @GBlodget but it must highlight that he is reffering to a variable that does not exist, but it ran perfectly for me too

Comment: @GBlodget ok sorry for that

Comment: @GBlodget what do you mean with *run perfectly? On my case it does not display anything if the res is not on the range (until I run again), although I am calling the function again randomQuestion();

Comment: @Cristea Correct me if I'm wrong but you never call `checkResult()` in the `randomQuestion()` method. So unless you call it directly, you'll never be checking the results (And by "run perfectly I meant no errors)

Comment: @GBlodgett you are right! I will have a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @GBlodgett This is because randomQuestion() is  calling checkResult()

Comment: @Cristea what GBlodgett said is true, but that will still not guarantee you that is printed out every time. Sometimes it will, sometimes not.. Check my answer.

Comment: @Cristea also, I don't see randomQuestion() calling checkResult(); here. Check again...

Comment: @Joza100 I though it would call again and again the method until the result is in the range. If you say that will not guaranty that, then the i should find another way to guaranty that (if there is a way). Thanks for your help ! 




     private void checkResult() {
  int res = randomQuestion();

Comment: @Cristea Here it will only run the second time because you used if statements. Check my answer there is the solution to guarantee. Also don't forget to call it somewhere too..

Comment: @Joza100 I dont find your answer :(

Comment: @Cristea just scroll down you will see my name

Comment: @GBlodgett This is what I wanted!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Cristea can you mark my answer as correct if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Others answered well, but the reason it doesn't display anything even after you run it twice is because it might not be in between even if you run it twice.

You need to use a while loop:

```
public void checkResult() {
    int res;
    //if the result is between 0 and 20 (inclusive)
        //First it runs once. 
        do {
            res = randomQuestion();

        //Here it checks if it is outside of the range and if it's outside  it will run again and again until it's inside of the range!
        } while (res < 0 || res > 20);

    System.out.println(res + " is between 0-20"); 
}
```

Also get yourself an IDE (Eclispe, Intellij IDEA)

Comment: do while loop has the same effect. does not print on the screen  if the res is out of range. Thanks!

Comment: @Cristea But the do while loop continues repeating it over and over again until it actually is in range. Did it help?

Comment: Was it very helpful! i very much appreciate all the help! :)

Comment: I woud happily give to you as well, but GBlodgett gave me the solution to all the issues I had.

Comment: @Cristea oh sorry. I actually thought that you told that to me that my answer was correct because you told me that. If his answer is the one that helped you then, I'm ok with it.